# Filter nested list python

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
a=[[(1,2),(7,-5),(7,4)],[(5,6),(7,2)],[(8,2),(20,7),(1,4)]]
```

A nested list of coordinates are as given in `a`.

For example `(1,2)` refers to `x,y` coordinates.

Imposing condition that `x,y> 0 & <10` and deleting those points.

```
for x in a:
    for y in x:
        for point in y:
            if point<=0 or point>=10:
                a.remove(x)
```

Expected result `a=[[(5,6),(7,2)]]`
This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: That error message doesn't match that code; that's a numpy error message, and you have no use of numpy arrays in that code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this list comprehesion.

```
>>> a = [[(1,2),(7,-5),(7,4)], [(5,6),(7,2)], [(8,2),(20,7),(1,4)]]
>>> [l for l in a if all((0<x<10 and 0<y<10) for x,y in l)]
[[(5, 6), (7, 2)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will print `[[(5, 6), (7, 2)]]`:

```
a=[[(1,2),(7,-5),(7,4)],[(5,6),(7,2)],[(8,2),(20,7),(1,4)]]

def f(sub):
  return all(map(lambda (x,y): (0 < x < 10 and 0 < y < 10), sub))

a = filter(f, a)
print a
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't read the question (or the input rather) carefully enough. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Better now :) You can make your `f` function quite a bit shorter by having both sides of the range, for instance `0 < point[0] < 10`

Comment: That's still wrong. The output should be` [[(5,6),(7,2)]]` that being the only sublist for which _all_ points meet the condition.

Comment: @mhawke Nice catch, totally missed that in the question.

Comment: Once again, i had not read the question carefully enough. Thanks, @mhawke, re-updated.

Comment: Don't see how a correct answer (albeit less elegant than @mhawke's answer) is worthy of a downvote.